# Create a plug-in (snap-in) for IIS Manager

Tags: c#-3.0, mmc

Is It possible to create a UI plug-in for IIS manager or the Windows server 2008 manager program?

Or is possible to create a MMC plug-in in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few links.

- CodeProject - creating a [snap-in](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mmcfileactcs.aspx)
- CodeProject - building a [snap-in application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/snapin.aspx)

I have not looked at these, but they should get you started.

Hope this helps and best of luck in your MMC snap-in development,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft ships [an MMC SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692740(VS.85).aspx), it was first shipped as part of the Windows Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003.

It allows you to build MMC "snap ins" in managed code.

Here's [a good basic tutorial](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/01/4384.aspx) covering the construction of a MMC snap-in in C#.